# Error al editar registro con Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Dentro de una tabla tengo un boton, que lleva a otra pestaña que contiene un formulario para editar el registro seleccionado.

Con useEffect estoy intentando llenar el formulario pero lo muestra vacio y en la consola aparece el siguiente error:

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

Tabla

```
  actions={[
      {
        icon: "iconname",
        onClick: (event, rowData) => 
        props.history.push(`/Articulo/edit/${rowData.Id}`)
      }
```

Editar Articulo

```
function EditarArticulo(props) {

    const [articulos, setArticulos]=useState({articulo: '',descripcion:'', precio:0})

    useEffect(function() {
        async function getArticulos() {
          try {
            const response = await  axios.get(`/api/Articulos/${props.match.params.Id}`);
            setArticulos(response.data);        
          } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        }
        getArticulos();    
      }, [props]);

      const handleSubmit=(event)=>{
          event.preventDefault();
          async function updateArticulos(){
              try {
                  await axios.put(`/api/Articulos/edit/${articulos.Id}`,articulos)
                  props.history.push('/Articulos')
              } catch (error) {
                  console.log(error)
              }
          }
          updateArticulos();
      }

      const handleChange=(event)=>{
          setArticulos({...articulos,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
      }

      return(
            <div>
                <Typography variant="h4" align="center">
                Editar 
                </Typography>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                    <div> 
                        <TextField
                            name="articulo"
                            type="text"
                            label="articulo"
                            value={articulos.articulo}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                        />
                        <TextField
                            name="descripcion"
                            type="text"
                            label="descripcion"}
                            value={articulos.descripcion}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                        />
                        <TextField
                            name="precio"
                            type="number"
                            label="precio"
                            value={articulos.precio}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            margin="normal"
                            variant="outlined"
                        />
                            <Button
                                onClick={handleSubmit} 
                                value="Submit"
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                type='submit'>
                                Edit
                            </Button>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
      )
}
```

Comment: `const response = await  axios.get('/api/Articulos/${props.match.params.Id}');` podrías mostrar un console log de que devuelve esto?

Comment: @VictorAlvarez `response.data
{message: "", success: true, registros: 1, Articulos: Array(1)}
props.match.params.Id
 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partiendo de la base de que la respuesta que recibes de `axios.get('/api/Articulos/${props.match.params.Id}');`

```
{message: "", success: true, registros: 1, Articulos: Array(1)}
```

Cambiar la parte donde asignas el valor a articulos

```
setArticulos(response.data.Articulos[0]);
```

Comment: Ahora estoy recibiendo el siguiente error: Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: eso seria un error que al hacer una petición no encuentra la url `/api/Articulos/${props.match.params.Id}` primero comprueba que este haciendo la petición correctamente a la url del api y que el parametro Id si se esta enviando